# Where can I ask about the behavior of a snake?

Tags: discussion, support

My last question on main site ([Can a certain snake kill human by 'drinking' his breaths?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/86626/16866)) has not been received well. So where can I ask about it? I don't think it's really a bad question. Many things can be found from it and maybe I can teach the locals about it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest instead of asking "is this myth true?" reframe your question as about the snake itself. Do some research yourself to find out how that particular snake is known to others (scientists) and try to find some information from other sources to frame your question.

"Is this myth true?" types of questions are exhausting to try to answer and often closed. Often they are based on things that are so false that they are [not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong) or haven't been subject to scientific study because they are completely meaningless in the context of science. Scientific study takes a lot of effort. Inventing myths does not.